# I'm missing something in this Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

** UPDATE **

- I change my approach and found a solution to my problem. I will add the final code that I used in the end. *

I've used this bit of code in the past to create a Google Calendar event from a Google Sheet. I'm trying to adapt it to fit a new sheet. This new sheet has a data entry form on the first sheet and a database sheet on a second tab. I've plugged all my cells into the function but I'm getting hung up on line 8. I think there is something I'm missing. Either I'm using the wrong function, i.e `.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetID();` Where maybe it's .getTab(), or something. Also, line 9 is telling me `ws.getSheetByName("Database")` is not a function. Should I declare `ss = ......` earlier and not as a `const`?

This is the old stuff. It's only being used in part.

```js
//Function to submit sheet data to Calendar Event///////////////////

const eventDuration = 2;
const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_rpejfrt7e50gblb5uo7ikphel0@group.calendar.google.com");

function createMultipleEvents() {
 
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetId();//Needs the Tab spreadsheet not the main
  const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Database");
  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created = ss.getRange(i, 12).getValue();
    if (created != "Event created") {
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue(); // Destination
      const speaker = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); // Ride Date
      const departTime = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); //Depart Time
      //const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); //Return Time
      //const deScription= ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Description
      var startingDate = new Date(date)

      var endingDate = new Date(date)

      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)
     
      calendar.createEvent(eventName, startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: speaker, description: deScription })
      ss.getRange(i, 12).setValue("Event created")
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Schedule!")
    .addItem(" Generate all events", "createMultipleEvents")
    .addSeparator()
    .addToUi();
}
```

In the end, I hadn't understood how google took in info for the calendar event. I also had a couple syntax errors. I ended up adding functions to submit to additional calendars. I am happy with this solution, but when the date is inputed into the description if the minute contain a zero it is omitted. Help with that would be useful. Although it isn't critical.
Here is the code:

```js
const eventDuration = 2;
const calendarTrans = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("walnuthillarts.org_llbhgoklvn21qqqd6kog63qvfg@group.calendar.google.com");
const calendarMedical = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("walnuthillarts.org_c0g39v7coeu8kp3ar9n0on8i30@group.calendar.google.com");

//Function for Medical Calendar
function createMedicalEvents()
{ 
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//
  const ss = ws.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created2 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    if (created2 == "Scheduled Medical") {
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes= date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone= ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date) 
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      calendarMedical.createEvent('Driver ?, '+rider+' '+eventName+', Depart WH@ ', startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n'+rider+', '+phone+'\n'+'\nDepart WH @'+hoursMinutes+'\nAppointment Time: '+apptTime+'\nDepart Appointment @'+returnTime})

      ss.getRange(i, 15).setValue("Medical Created")
    }
    else if (created2 == "Urgent Care") {
      const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes= date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone= ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date) 
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      calendarMedical.createEvent('Driver ?, '+rider+' '+eventName+', Depart WH@ ', startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n'+rider+', '+phone+'\n'+'\nDepart WH @'+hoursMinutes+'\nAppointment Time: '+apptTime+'\nDepart Appointment @'+returnTime})

      ss.getRange(i, 15).setValue("Medical Created")
    }
  }

}

function createTransportationEvents() 
{ 
  const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//
  const ss = ws.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 2; i <= ss.getLastRow(); i++) {
    const created1 = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
    const created2 = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    
    if (created1 != "Event Created") {
     const eventName = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); // Title
      const location = ss.getRange(i, 8).getValue(); // Destination
      const rider = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue(); // Rider
      const date = ss.getRange(i, 9).getValue(); // Ride Date and Departure time
      const apptTime = ss.getRange(i, 10).getValue(); //Appointment Time
      const returnTime = ss.getRange(i, 11).getValue(); //Return Time (Depart Location to return to WH)
      const hoursMinutes= date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes(); // Time of departure for Description Text
      const phone= ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue(); //Phone Number
      var startingDate = new Date(date) 
      var endingDate = new Date(date)
      endingDate.setHours(startingDate.getHours() + eventDuration)

      calendarTrans.createEvent('Driver ?, '+rider+' '+eventName+', Depart WH@ ', startingDate, endingDate, { location: location, description: 'Driver:\n \nRider:\n'+rider+', '+phone+'\n'+'\nDepart WH @'+hoursMinutes+'\nAppointment Time: '+apptTime+'\nDepart Appointment @'+returnTime})

      ss.getRange(i, 14).setValue("Event Created") 
    }

  }
}

// Create a Button to schedule events
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("  Submit")
    .addItem("Medical", "createMedicalEvents")
    .addSeparator()
    .addItem("Transportation", "createTransportationEvents")
    .addToUi();
}

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Thanks everyone!
-TrauzerHamz

Comment: About your current issue of `but I'm getting hung up on line 8`, in order to use `ws` to `const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Database");`, please modify `const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetId();` to `const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`, and test it again.

Comment: Whoa, that was fast. Thanks. I'm no longer getting an error at line 8. Now it's just hanging.

Comment: I think I know why it's hanging. When I use the onOpen from the button created in the sheet, it begins inputing "Event Created" into column 12. Which it should do on ly once per row with data. If no data is present it should stop. Does conditional formatting count as data?

Comment: @TrauzerHamz Empty cells "count as data" as `getValue()`returns a empty string. Please read [Troubleshooting > debugging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging). If you need further help please update the question and add a brief description of you debugging efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Tanaike and @Ruben. I am very new to programming as you can probably tell. I have made some edits at my end, but I'm having trouble getting the `startTime` and `returnTime` to pass into the event start and end for the calendar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. But I'm surprised that your question had been changed. When I saw your changed question, unfortunately, my proposed modification is not reflected in your current showing script. And also, at `{ location: location, description: speaker, description: deScription }`, `description` is used 2 times, and `deScription` is not declared. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation. I apologize for this. Can you update your question by correctly reflecting on your current situation?

Comment: @Tanaike - Forgive my ignorance. This is the first time I've used stackoverflow. I'm just now realizing there is a protocol to this process. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to annotate the snippet with the changes. I apologize. As I've been. Researching today I think I've narrowed the problem down to the way I'm trying to get the start time. It's inputed into the spreadsheet via a drop down list in a cell on a different tab. I would like to use that time as the start time for the even.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.